# Require DocumentDB on asp.net-core MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use DocumentDB on asp.net-core MVC App (using VSCode - Mac OS X) and I'm having trouble configuring the `project.json` file, my configuration looks as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB": "1.11.0"
  }
```

But on solving the dependencies vscode throws me:

```
 Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.11.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0).
```

I downloaded the code that's used on the example in the emulator (for Windows :() and the dependency is as follows:

```
 "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client": "0.1.0"
```

I checked that dependency and is marked as deprecated and it's not really available.

Do you know what is the correct Dependency for using DocumentDB in a asp.net-core app (using vscode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently `DocumentDB .NET Core` is available with preview version only. So you need preview version of the `DocumentDB .NET Core` client library. You can add it using nuget package manager.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core -Pre
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the dependency:

```
 "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core": "0.1.0-preview"
```